# ExpressionEngine not showing when there are no comments

Tags: html, content-management-system, expressionengine

I can't seem to figure out why ExpressionEngine is not displaying the message when there are when there are no comments. The way it works now, when there are no comments nothing is displayed. When there is one comment, the comment is displayed. I also noticed when there are no comments it won't execute anything inside of the comment:entries loop.

```
{exp:comment:entries channel="article" url_title="{segment_4}" orderby="{entry_date}" sort="desc" dynamic=“no”}
    {if no_results}
        <p>Nothing has been said yet. <a href="#leave-a-comment">Write something.</a></p>
    {/if}

        {comment}
        <p class="comment-by">By {if "{url}" != ""}<a href="{url}">{name}</a>{if:else}{name}{/if}  on {comment_date format="%Y %m, %d"}</p>
{/exp:comment:entries}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unable to test this, but you have `dynamic="no"` on, and `url_title="{segment_4}"`.

`dynamic="no"` prevents the URI from having any effect on the content of a weblog. Whether this has any effect when the `url_title` is specified using a `{segment_x}` variable, I do not know. (This is speculation)

However your code seems needlessly complicated, when the following will work fine for a single page entry:

```
{exp:comment:entries sort="asc" limit="20"}
{if no_results} There are no comments... {/if}    

{comment}

<p>By {name} on {comment_date format="%Y %m %d"}</p>

{/exp:comment:entries}
```

You don't need to specify channel/url_title in the comments tag (assuming you are on a single page entry, which I believe you are from your post).

Try that, see if you get the desired result.